# Meteor-React Error: Target Container is not a DOM element, after fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I copy+paste the code from : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514549/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151454)

Then, I fix error and change 'class' by 'id' so:

**main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>React Meteor Voting</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="render-target"></div>
</body>
```

**main.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-target'));
});

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-react",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  }
}
```

But I got the same error:

> Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM
>   element.
>           at invariant (modules.js?hash=de726ed…:12672)
>           at Object._renderNewRootComponent (modules.js?hash=de726ed…:30752)
>           at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (modules.js?hash=de726ed…:30842)
>           at render (modules.js?hash=de726ed…:30863)
>           at app.js?hash=71ef103…:46
>           at maybeReady (meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:809)
>           at HTMLDocument.loadingCompleted (meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:821)

Is driving me crazy....  ¡¡¡¡¡

Comment: I get the same... Meteor was just updated to 1.7 - I ran the tutorial 2 weeks ago when it was still 1.6. Then everything worked. Could they have broken something?  https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components

Comment: Won't it be better to use 'meteor create --react'? instead of going through the hassle of creating and then removing the default blaze-template and then add static-html? Nice comment but I believe the best way to go about such error is my removing the default blaze-html-template the follows the creation by simply using your command line(command prompt as the case may) to "meteor remove blaze-html-template" and then "meteor add static-html". I believe this approach will minimize the in the code better.

Comment: thanks for this thread, it was making me crazy. Sadly Scott doesn't update his courses, which is a shame as he is really smart and his content is A-class.

Answer (score 48):

Basically, the problem occurs due to HTML rendering. When you create meteor app it comes up with the blaze by default & you are working on the meteor with react or meteor with angular. You solve this error by two methods.

**Method 1**
just add import statement in main.js

`import './main.html'`;

**Method  2** Preferrable as it is my choice

```
meteor remove blaze-html-templates
meteor add static-html
```

Comment: better answer because of the explanation

Comment: Thanks @niccolom.

Comment: It works, But if you face any problems after removing adding,, just re-start your app again.

Comment: If you plan to use Meteor's user account UI you should to use Method 1 (import './main.html') as the User account UI requires Blaze templates. This is true for the 'Todos App with React' tutorial.

Answer (score 29):

If you removed `blaze-html-templates` you need to add `static-html` package to compile your `index.html` and avoid this error (see [Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-with-meteor), end of paragraph):

```
 meteor add static-html
```

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. This is how I solved it.

In your terminal type the following lines in the project directory.

```
meteor remove blaze-html-templates
meteor add static-html
```

Comment: If you are using Steven Grider's Udemy course on Meteor, this is the answer.

Comment: This worked for me. i wonder why it is not in the official tutorial documentation

Answer (score 8):

For me I just needed to import the .html file before I tried to render to the DOM.

`import './main.html';`

Answer (score 5):

```
meteor remove blaze-html-templates
meteor add static-html
```

Comment: Add some description to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Add your script tag to before the closing `</body>` tag most likely the script loaded before your DOM ID.

also switch this around...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
    );
  }
}

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-target'));
});
```

Comment: I had already tried this, with the same result, the same ERROR.  Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you say with: "Add your script tag" .  It is necessary with Meteor ?

Answer (score 1):

First remove blaze template dependency

```
meteor remove blaze-html-templates
```

Then add  static html

```
meteor add static-html
```

Comment: please use formatting for better readability :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

I had removed the package (blaze-html-templates) .

I assumed that being a Meteor+React would not be necessary  but it is used to compile the main.html.

Adding the package blaze-html-templates with

**meteor add blaze-html-templates**

solve the problem.

Comment: You don't need `blaze-html-templates`, but if you remove it you need to add `static-html` package:

Answer (score 0):

In my case the fix was simple. In HTML change class to id.

```
render( <h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById("app"))

<body>
<div class="app"><`enter code here`/div>
</body>

<body>
<div id="app"><`enter code here`/div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but it's #1 in google results so...

I was getting this error on my android build but not web, already removed blaze and added statichtml..

My issue ended up being that I had a favicon and manifest.json being imported in my html but I hadn't gotten around to creating them yet.

I removed the links and it worked like a charm.

Hopefully this can save someone a few hours of digging.