# Meteor + React - Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, dom, meteor, render

I'm getting this error when following meteor-react tutorial: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app

[JavaScript Console debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF1GE.png)

My app is in **Meteor v1.7.0.1**.

My **client/main.js** file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from './imports/ui/App.js';


Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-target'));
});
```

And my **client/main.html** is this:

```
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="render-target"></div>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507161/meteor-react-error-target-container-is-not-a-dom-element-after-fix your question has already been answered here, it's kind of duplicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor-React Error: Target Container is not a DOM element, after fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507161/meteor-react-error-target-container-is-not-a-dom-element-after-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `ReactDOM` import? You need `react-dom` to work in the browser. Install it in your terminal like so:

`npm install --save react-dom`

Then I would refactor like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './main.html';
```

Also, where is your component? Create one like so:

```
const App = () => {
  return <div>React App #2</div>;
};
```

And then render it like so:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
});
```