# meteor js 1.7.0.5 wont access database on mac

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am a noob to meteor and have tried very hard to follow some tutorials on getting mongodb access to work. I have installed meteor 1.7.0.5 on a mac and have tried to run the https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app tutorial up to step 3. I can see my data in the meteor mongo console, but it does not appear in my web app even though I have followed the instructions up to step 3. weirdly I have managed to get exactly this same code working on a raspberry pi.

I was looking at meteor as a possible alternative to firestore, but the problems are starting to put me off of wanting to use meteor js in future projects.

Comment: Without some code, it's hard to see where you might be going wrong.

Comment: meteor will auto spin up a mini mongo server which works out of the box, no separate install needed and will let you persist data for life time of that meteor launch ...  however for any real development you will want a stand alone mongo server which your code will auto recognize and connect to

Comment: Do you have autopublish turned on?

Comment: thanks for all the helpful replies. the code is as written on the meteor web site and all steps have been followed, (with npm installs) up to the end of this bit: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections. On the pi it all worked as written, on the mac nothing seems to happen. as for autopublish I dont know anything about this option, but I didnt need it on the raspberry pi.

Comment: meteor-base and autopublish were installed into the project, but this hasnt made a difference. I think i have fallen foul of an issue reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507161/meteor-react-error-target-container-is-not-a-dom-element-after-fix

Comment: I think this is fixed now.it must be something to do with version 1.7.0.5 and dependencies